# Mathf.Pow Shows Infinity on C#

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger

I'm trying to calculate a big number using `Mathf.Pow()` but when I place a breakpoint it shows infinity, I already tried using `System.Numerics.BigInteger` but it shows *Big Integer cannot display infinity*

Here's my code

```
    using System;
using System.Numerics;
namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //43
            BigInteger res = new BigInteger(MathF.Pow(43, 27));
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If MathF.Pow returned Single.PositiveInfinity, creating a new BigInteger isn't going to change the answer. You could try BigInteger.Pow instead.

Comment: `MathF.Pow` returns a `float`, so the maximum value you can possibly get is `3.40282347E+38`.

Comment: BigInteger.Pow() Worked as a charm! You can post it as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeremy said

> You could try BigInteger.Pow instead

I used `BigInteger res = BigInteger.Pow(43,27);` and that worked, thanks!